# How can you disallow an item in a ListBox from being selected?

Tags: wpf, listbox, focus, selection

We're trying to create a ListBox which has a few items inside that the user cannot select.  Think the group headings in a grouped listbox, except these are independent items (i.e. no indented children.)  We just want to display a message in the list.

Here's a mock-up of what we currently display if there are 'Foo' items...

```
Foo 1
Foo 2
Foo 3
--------------   <-- This is of type 'Separator' so it's styled as not-selectable by default.
Add new Foo...
Manage Foos...
```

...and if there aren't any Foo items, we display this...

```
[No Foo Items]   <-- This one should not be selectable, the same as a separator
--------------   <-- This is of type 'Separator' so it's styled as not-selectable by default.
Add new Foo...
Manage Foos...
```

Now again, we already have the code that properly handles what's displayed (see below).  We're wondering what's the proper way to disable that entry from being able to be selected.

What we don't know is how to style that ListBoxItem so the selection skips right over it, nor can the user click on it.

### Code

Someone asked me to see my code, so here it is.  Not really relevant to the question, but should show people how I did this.

Note: We template the `string.Empty` in the XAML to show the localized 'No xxx Items' message.  `string.Empty` is just a placeholder that we can target.

Note 2: FauxData is a simple library of items and collections used for testing so I don't have to constantly create them from scratch.  SimpleItemCollection for instance creates ten SimpleItem objects in the constructor, pre-populated with things like Name, Description, IsSelected, etc. all fully supporting INotifyPropertyChanged and collection change notifications.  I have the same thing with HierarchicalItemsCollection which adds Parent, Children and IsExpanded, etc. It saves a LOT of work when testing code and controls!

Finally, this is from a simple test, or 'playground' app. As such, it's not supposed to represent the best way to do things, just to show a concept. Yes, it can be cleaned up a lot, but you get the general idea.

Anyway, on to the code...

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using FauxData;

namespace Playground.ListTest
{
    [LaunchEntry("List Test")]
    public partial class Main : Window
    {
        SimpleItemCollection itemsCollection = new SimpleItemCollection(); // Default constructor creates 10 items

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainListBox.ItemsSource = CreateCompositeCollection();
        }

        private CompositeCollection CreateCompositeCollection()
        {
            var EmptyHolder = new ObservableCollection<object>();

            itemsCollection.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => {

                if(itemsCollection.Count != 0)
                    EmptyHolder.Clear();
                else if(EmptyHolder.Count == 0)
                    EmptyHolder.Add(string.Empty);

            };

            var cc = new CompositeCollection();

            cc.Add(new CollectionContainer(){ Collection = itemsCollection });
            cc.Add(new CollectionContainer(){ Collection = EmptyHolder });
            cc.Add(new Separator());
            cc.Add(ApplicationCommands.New);   // <-- Pops a dialog to enter a new item
            cc.Add(ApplicationCommands.Open);  // <-- Shows an item management window

            return cc;

        }

        private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(itemsCollection.Count != 0)
                itemsCollection.Clear();
            else
                itemsCollection.Add(new SimpleItem(){Name = "New item" });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Focusable="false"` does not cover all options (e.g. click and drag select) i would recommend setting `IsEnabled` to `false` instead.

*(The greyed out text is a matter of the `ListBoxItem` style/template, so if you do not like it you will need to override it)*

Comment: We actually throw in a `string.Empty` object which we style with a simple `DataTemplateMapping` selector and style it as we see fit (including the actual text message itself.)  It's basically a selector which we can define completely in XAML and can map against values, types, null or even specify a default template if all other matches fail.  It's really convenient as again, it's pure XAML.

Comment: Well... it partially worked.  If you multi-select, you can still select the item, so it's not 100%.  I think this may require a custom ListBoxItem container that explicitly ignores the Selector.IsSelected property via validation/coercion, etc. (I'm gonna un-check this as the accepted answer to get more people looking at finding something that works, but if they don't, then I'll re-mark this one.)

Comment: @MarqueIV: Well, i knew that `IsEnabled` is not perfect either, to be honest i would not use it and instead try to not have anything in the items collection which i do not want to be selectable, though just getting in visual separators is not easy as the control is not really meant for this.

Comment: But a grouping ListBox does this just fine!  All the group headers, even when nested all appear, but aren't ever part of the selection.  I guess it's time to bust out Snoop and see what the heck they're doing in there.

Comment: Well, grouping is built in, having arbitrary elements probably is not, though if the grouping mechanism does not use anything internal you may be able to use the same method.

Comment: For me this works and I don't see how drag select should be able to select anything: <ListBox>
      <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Style>
      </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <ListBoxItem>FIRST</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>SECOND</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>THIRD</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

Comment: @Wouter: It's probably only an issue if `SelectionMode = Extended`; that it was a problem i am sure of.

Comment: @H.B. For me it works in any mode. Could it it be fixed in a more recent framework version? To be on the safe side I was trying to reproduce the drag select problem.

Comment: @Wouter: Possible, but why not just do it the semantically correct way and disable the items?

Comment: @H.B. I agree IsEnabled is more suited. Just got across this when trying to solve a problem where changing the selected item is only allowed after asking the user to save, preferably without reverting the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! That was easy!  On the `ListBoxItem` you want to skip, you just set `Focusable` to `False`.

Done and done!

Comment: There is a reason why Gerd deleted his answer saying the same thing: It does not guarantee anything, click and drag over the list and you will still be able to select it. (You should set `IsEnabled` to `false` instead)

Comment: @H.B. Even better!  Post it as an answer and I'll mark yours as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to gray out then IsHitTestVisible seems to achieve that.

```
    <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="False">HEsder</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="True">1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem IsHitTestVisible="False">-----</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem IsEnabled="True">2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

If you are Binding the you would need to user a trigger.

Comment: This works with SelectionMode="Multiple".  One Extended with a Shift it highlights but is a user really going to be confused.  The class should be smart enough to know it is a place holder.

Comment: I ran into an issue where I was getting a red border in my adorner layer when I would click an item in my listbox.  Setting IsHitTestVisible=false removed the red border when the user clicked an item.